# Swipe and Scroll keywords stopped working in AWS Device Farm with Appium library

Tags: android, ios, appium, robotframework, aws-device-farm

I have used Robot Framework with Appium library to automate test cases in AWS' Device Farm. For some reason all Scroll and Swipe keywords have stopped working there (with real devices attached), concerning both Android and iOS test phones.
Does anyone know, what has happened? I have googled and the problem isn't shared anywhere I could find. Is it an update issue or maybe a law issue? The Device Farm runs in the US, and they have quite a few laws to prevent from automating things.

This could also be a web driver issue. The error message looks like this:

> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'w3c'

I have no idea what web driver version (of Chrome web driver I suppose) Device Farm uses and if it could be re-configured at all.

Note that on my locale testing laptop with an Android emulator, everything works fine as before.

As you can guess, this is a showstopper in testing native mobile application. Swipe and/or scroll is required every time the content is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using aws device farm, but I know, that scroll, swipe and other touch actions it's a part of breaking changes on the way to the w3c compilance.

https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/
https://appiumpro.com/editions/29-automating-complex-gestures-with-the-w3c-actions-api

And both server and client sides may switch the legacy command protocol to w3c. If you haven't change appium client lib versions, possibly something changed on aws cloud side.

Browsing the device farm docs I found, that it's possible to define appium server version.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-appium.html

I suggest to define some earlier appium vesion and try to run tests again.

Also you can address this issue to aws support team.